# how to scroll down with selenium in python script?

Tags: python, selenium

I need to scroll down in a dialog box to find more comments, like this:

https://www.google.com/search?q=parque+ibirapuera&sxsrf=ALeKk02LtOuOMcY370--DnAM74bYzZiQyA%3A1627773313999&ei=gdkFYda0PNSc5OUP0MKCoA0&gs_ssp=eJzj4tTP1TewNI8vNDNgtFI1qLA0SU41tUwzNDCzTDE0TDG0MqhITrI0NjM0sExMswTKmRh6CRYkFhWWpipkJmUWJRaUphYlAgCKlhRj&oq=parque+ib&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMYADIRCC4QgAQQsQMQxwEQrwEQkwIyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyCwguEIAEEMcBEK8BMg4ILhCABBCxAxDHARCvATIFCAAQgAQ6BggjECcQEzoECCMQJzoECC4QQzoLCAAQgAQQsQMQgwE6CwguEIAEELEDEIMBOgQIABBDOggIABCABBCxAzoHCAAQsQMQQzoFCC4QgAQ6CAguEIAEELEDOg4ILhCxAxCDARDHARCvAToFCAAQsQNKBAhBGABQpSJYyCpgpTNoAHACeACAAboBiAGQDJIBBDAuMTCYAQCgAQHAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz#lrd=0x94ce59f1069d11d1:0xcb936109af9ce541,1,,,

I'm using selenium to do that:

```
    scrollable_div = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
 'body.srp.wf-b.vsc-initialized:nth-child(2) div.ynlwjd.VDgVie.oLLmo.u98ib:nth-child(2) div.AU64fe.zsYMMe.TUOsUe div.VFlF2c.review-dialog div.Zd3Ymd.review-dialog-body div.lcorif.fp-w div.review-dialog-list > div.loris:nth-child(6)'
                     )
driver.execute_script(
               'arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight', 
                scrollable_div
               )
```

with this error: *selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"body.srp.wf-b.vsc-initialized:nth-child(2) div.ynlwjd.VDgVie.oLLmo.u98ib:nth-child(2) div.AU64fe.zsYMMe.TUOsUe div.VFlF2c.review-dialog div.Zd3Ymd.review-dialog-body div.lcorif.fp-w div.review-dialog-list > div.loris:nth-child(6)"}*

Answer (score 0):

That website is indeed very cumbersome to deal with. But here is how you can get this done.

1. Import the powerful [Action Chains](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains) module of selenium

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

2. Locate the appropriate element (you can use another element as well)

```
el = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#reviewSort > div:nth-child(1) > div.gws-localreviews__general-reviews-block > div:nth-child(1)')
```

3. Perform `move`, `click_and_hold` and `send_keys` operations on the element simultaneously

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(el).click_and_hold().send_keys(Keys.END).perform()
```

Comment: Didn't work for me! Same error: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#reviewSort > div:nth-child(1) > div.gws-localreviews__general-reviews-block > div:nth-child(1)"}

Comment: I just re-ran the code and it is working for me. Can you share the full code?